# Generalization of Jacobi symbol for higher powers?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Let $n$ be an odd positive integer of unknown factorization, and let $x$ be relatively prime to $n$.  The Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ gives me partial information on whether $x$ is a square modulo $n$ (in particular, if $\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=-1$, then $x$ is certainly not a square).  Also, the Jacobi symbol can be evaluated efficiently (in polynomial time), given $x$ and $n$ as input, without needing to know the factorization of $n$.

Is there a generalization of the Jacobi symbol that gives me information about whether $x$ is a $k$th power modulo $n$, when $k>2$?  And if so, can it be computed in polynomial time, given $x$ and $n$ as input, without knowing the factorization of $n$?  In particular, is there any known generalization that satisfies both of these criteria (gives me information about whether $x$ is a $k$th power; computable efficiently without knowing the factorization of $n$)?

You can focus on the case where $k$ divides $\varphi(n)$, since the other cases follow straightforwardly from that one.

Answer (score 2):

There are a pair of generalizations.

You are looking for either the [power residue symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_residue_symbol) or the [Hilbert symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol) (which are very closely related).

These should be computable, since computing norms of ideals in number fields is a reasonable computation. For highly composite moduli you would need to be able to factor, but this problem is present for the Jacobi symbol too.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'd benefit from an explanation at a more elementary level (I'm clueless about algebraic number fields, prime ideals in them, etc.) -- any ideas where to find a more elementary exposition of this? For example, what would these look like for giving information about whether $x$ is a cube modulo $n$? (Separately, I confess I'm a bit lost by the statement about highly composite moduli. As far as I know, the Jacobi symbol has no problem with highly composite moduli $n$, as long as $n$ is odd.) If the answer is that I'd need more math background to understand this, I understand!